# php checkbox array access

Tags: php, html, arrays

```
$i=0;
while (db_data) {
$i++;
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="v['.$i.']" value="'.$url.'"';
if ($v[$i]) {
  echo ' checked';
  $s .= $url;
}
echo '/>';

}
```

I have the above array of checkboxes. It worked on my pc, but not on the server; it seems like the confusing part is on `$v[$i]`.

$v is not defined, but sure used no where else. the problem is my checkbox selection never restored, and code never get into the if statement.

however, if i add the following, i can see the value. just the checkbox lost after the processing
    $v=$_POST['v'];
    while (list ($key,$val) = @each ($v)) { 
    $x .= ' 11*'.$key.'-'.$val.'*22 '; 
    }

my goal is to preserve the checkbox checked on the form, and i need the $s elsewhere. any solution to replace $v[$i]?

Can anybody help me fix this? Thank you.

Comment: Did you copy/paste this incorrectly?

Comment: huh ? sorry but there isn't enough to go on here could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Where are `$v` and `$i` defined? Your code sample is obviously incomplete.

Comment: Please add what you expect to see and what you actually see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<del>The issue seems to be $v = $_POST.  If you are just doing that then your conditional statement would need to be</del>

```
if ($v['v'][$i]) {
   ///Checkbox
}
```

or just do $v = $_POST['v'].

Sorry, ignore above as you did mention you did that part.  See below.

Here is working code.

```
<form action="" method="post">
<?php
$v = $_POST['v'];
$i=0;
while ($i < 4) {
    $i++;
    $url = "test.com/".$i;
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="v['.$i.']" value="'.$url.'"';
    if ($v[$i]) {  
        echo ' checked="checked"';  
        $s .= $url;
    }
    echo '/> '.$url.'<br />';
}
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

I left the code pretty much the same to show you where you went wrong, but you should be checking the $_POST variable for exploits before using.  If I were doing this as well, I would use a for count, but it's setup as a placeholder for your database code.  Make sure that $url gets populated as well.

You could also do away with the $i variable like:

```
<?php
$v = $_POST['v'];
while (db_data) {
    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="v[]" value="'.$url.'"';
    if (is_array($v)) {
         if (in_array($url,$v)) {  
              echo ' checked="checked"';  
              $s .= $url;
         }
    }
    echo '/> '.$url.'<br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: it rocks! the best help i got! you guys are great!

Answer (score 0):

Try to print_r($_POST) and then print_r($v) and see if anything comes up.  If the $_POST works, then you know that it is being posted back to the page correctly.  Then if the $v is working, then you know you set $v = $_POST correctly.  Due to the fact that you don't actually give us any information on the db_data, I assume this is working correctly and displaying all the checkboxes on first load, so as long as it is posted and you are setting the $v variable, it should be working.

A side note is that you should validate the $_POST variables before using, but do that after you get things working.

Comment: If you do what FatherStorm said above (I can't comment on it I guess because of being a new user), then you need to use is_array and in_array, which may work out better anyways.

Comment: i know the _POST is working, since the while loop worked. the problem is the checked box is lost immediately

Answer (score 0):

change

```
name="v['.$i.']"
```

to

```
name="v[]"
```

the fact that PHP picks that up as an array is a unintended feature of PHP that wasn't intentionally designed. you don't need to set the indexes, just define it as an array.

Comment: no, i have to set the index, otherwise, it will store as the v0, v1, v2...in order, no matter what stuff i choose.